# Get href value from <a/> who is store in a variable ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, href, erb

My entire code :

```
<% query.inline_columns.each do|column| %>
    <% if column.css_classes.to_s != "assigned_to" %>
         <td class="<%= column.css_classes %>"> <%= column_content(column, issue) %> </td>
    <% else %>
         <td class="<%= column.css_classes %>"> <%= test = column_content(column, issue) %> </td>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have something like that:

```
test = column_content(column, issue)
```

and when i go on the website it give me something like that:

```
<a class="user active" href="/users/5">Test</a>
```

My question is how can I get the value of href ? 
I tried test.href, test.link_to and test.link but don't work.

And after when we have the href it's possible to only have the id in href ? (In the href above it's 5)
**BUT I don't want to go on page and get the id, I just want to have it so I can load the picture of user in the table.**

I'm beginner in ERB language, thank's for help !

**EDIT**:
My solution to get the id :

```
test.to_s.split("href=\"").last.to_s.split("\"").first.to_s.split("/").last.to_s
```

Thank's guy to try to help me !

Comment: What are you actually asking, do you want to parse a HTML snippet? Send a parameter to a controller?

Comment: I have a table with all data in and i have a column "assigned_to" with the user name and the href link. But i don't have the id of user, so i wan't to take the id from the href link.

Comment: This would be handled by the routing, which would send you to eg the users#show action with params[:id] = 5, read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: You mean to extract the `id` of the record from the row you click in browser?

Answer (score 0):

### The Request cycle:

In Rails and in MVC every request follows a cycle:

Let's say you type in `http://localhost:3000/users`.

1. The request hits your Rails server and goes through Rack to your routes.
2. Rails picks a controller and action which matches the request.
3. Rails runs your `UsersController#index` and renders the view.
4. The rendered html is sent back to the client.

So why am I telling you this?

#### It has nothing to do with `ERB`.

You simply render the view and send it to the client - all done. The client can interact by clicking links or submitting forms. But it's not your actual view communicating back.

When the user clicks the link it starts a whole new request - it's a whole new process*.

#### Routes & Params

Routes are kind of like regular expressions - with superpowers.

If you want your rails app to handle the request to `/users/1` you need to create a route:

```
 # config/routes.rb
 get `/users/:id`, to: 'users#show'
```

See the `:id` part? That means we can get the ID passed in the url from `params[:id]`.

```
class UsersController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Of course writing your routes like that is pretty tedious. So instead we write:

```
resources :users
```

Try running `rake routes` from the console to see what it does.

Comment: * kind of. But thats a topic for later.